# Snapshot.data is always returning null while getting data from sqlite database in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-sqlite, sqflite

This keeps happening although there is data in the database. I'm new to flutter and I've been trying to fix this problem for almost three days now. **snapshot.data** is returning null and I don't know why because I have enough data in the database.

Below is the **db_helper.dart** file.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:com.example.simple_app/models/person.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database db_instance;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (db_instance == null) {
      db_instance = await initDB();
    }
    return db_instance;
  }

  initDB() async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'simpleapp.db');
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: onCreateFunc);
    return db;
  }

  void onCreateFunc(Database db, int version) async {
    // create table
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE persons(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, created DATETIME, updated DATETIME);');
  }

   /// crud functions

  Future<List<Person>> getAllPersons() async {
    final db_connection = await db;
    var response = await db_connection.query("Person");
    List<Person> list = response.map((c) => Person.fromMap(c)).toList();
    return list;
  }

  // add new person
  void addNewPerson(Person person) async {
    var db_connection = await db;
    String query = """
        INSERT INTO persons(name,created,updated) VALUES('${person.name}','${person.created}', '${person.updated}')
        """;
    await db_connection.transaction((transaction) async {
      print(query);
      return await transaction.rawInsert(query);
    });
  }
}
```

Below is **home.dart** file where I'm trying to display the data from the database in `FutereBuilder` but snapshot is always returning null, which is resulting in the loader circle circling all time.

```dart
import 'package:com.example.simple_app/models/person.dart';
import 'package:com.example.simple_app/utils/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:com.example.simple_app/common_widgets/appbar.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

var dbHelper = DBHelper();

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [];
  static const TextStyle moneyLendingAction =
      TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller_name = new TextEditingController();

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: appbar(context, 'Simple App', 'other data'),
      body: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Person>>(
          future: dbHelper.getAllPersons(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Person>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Person item = snapshot.data[index];
                  return Dismissible(
                    background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {},
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(item.name),
                      subtitle: Text(item.name),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(item.id.toString())),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              // because snapshot.data is returning null, this is showing all time.
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); 
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Below is the **person.dart** model file.

```dart
class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
  DateTime created, updated;

  Person({this.id, this.name, this.created, this.updated});

  factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Person(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        created: json["created"],
        updated: json["updated"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "created": created,
        "updated": updated,
      };
}
```

What I want is to show the data from the database in the `FutureBuilder`. And please don't tell me this is duplicate because I have checked similar questions and I don't see any question that relates to what is happening in my code.
Thank you, posted with love.

Comment: tried to `print(response)` inside `getAllPersons()` method? or even better `print(list)`?

Comment: Yes, I getting this log..

Comment: so? what is inside that log?

Comment: `Restarted application in 2,915ms.
I/flutter (17658): [{id: 1, name: hhsw, created: 2020-01-04 10:08:59.554133, updated: 2020-01-04 10:08:59.554247}, {id: 2, name: hajdj, created: 2020-01-04 10:10:02.257511, updated: 2020-01-04 10:10:02.257616}]`

Comment: ok so remove that `print` and now before `if (snapshot.hasData) {` just call `print(snapshot)`

Comment: `Restarted application in 3,581ms.
I/flutter (17658): AsyncSnapshot<List<Person>>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)
I/flutter (17658): AsyncSnapshot<List<Person>>(ConnectionState.done, null, type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime')`

Comment: `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'` most likely you have a problem inside `Person.fromMap()` method - tried to `print(list)` inside `getAllPersons()`? does it even go there?

Comment: Oh you are right bro. But how can I fix this issue since I also need the to use the dates coming from the database.. I have updated the code see the **person.dart** model file.

Comment: use http://app.quicktype.io, select "Dart" as a language and paste `[{"id": 1, "name": "hhsw", "created": "2020-01-04 10:08:59.554133", "updated": "2020-01-04 10:08:59.554247"}]` as json input

Comment: Your comment it's helpful but I'm new to flutter and dart so I don't understand very much what is going on there. When I replace the `Person` class in my code with the one generated [here](http://app.quicktype.io), new problems are occurring. If possible please provide answer of already solved problem.

Comment: did you see generated `fromJson()` method? so change your `Person.fromMap()` method accordingly

Comment: Thank you man, I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: sure, your welcome - of course you need to change `toMap()` method too

Comment: Yes I did that. everything is working now, I can see the data list now in the `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: good, thats really good

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast date strings from JSON response

`created: DateTime.parse(data['created_at'].toString()),
 updated: DateTime.parse(data['date'].toString()),`